# Create Multiarch package with prebuild binaries

Tags: packaging, multiarch

Hi I am currently trying to create a package with prebuild binaries
as for the source I have a binaries directory with a 32 and 64 subdirectory.

I would like to install the 64bit binaries on a 64bit system and vice versa.
How do I achieve this in the debian/*.install script?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking seems to me weird, as it looks you had jumped over the regular workflow.

1. Developer: Have source code
2. Developer: Add build & install script (`make`, `automake`, `cmake`, ..etc)
3. Packager: Get source archive
4. Packager: Make Debian package
   (3. Could be skipped when building native Debian package directly from source tree)

It is more convenient to handle multi-arch installation at 2nd step while installing. So you get a generic installation way. Then move on to clean Debian package. This will make maintaining it more easier too.